# Mockito "when" clause gets NPE in Method.getParameterTypes(), but only in Maven build, not in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, mockito

I'm working on a unit test that I had written a while ago and thought was working.  I'm now finding that it does not fail in Eclipse, but fails with a NPE when run in the Maven build.

I'm using mockito-core v5.5.0.

The test method that fails is the following:

```
@Test
public void testfilterFeatureEnabled() throws Exception {
    when(featureToggle.havingValue()).thenReturn("stuff");
    when(activationStrategy.isApplicable(any(Feature.class))).thenReturn(true); // 54
    when(activationStrategy.havingValue(any(Feature.class), anyString())).thenReturn(true);
    
    featureToggleFilter.filter(reqContext);
    
    verify(reqContext, never()).abortWith(any(Response.class));
}
```

The initial part of the class, showing what is being mocked, is this:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class FeatureToggleFilterTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private FeatureToggleFilter featureToggleFilter;

    @Mock
    private FeatureToggle featureToggle;

    @Mock
    private ActivationStrategy  activationStrategy;

    @Mock
    private ContainerRequestContext reqContext;
```

The stacktrace in the Maven build shows this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameterTypes(Method.java:311)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.DelegatingMethod.<init>(DelegatingMethod.java:20)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.DefaultInvocationFactory.createMockitoMethod(DefaultInvocationFactory.java:81)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.DefaultInvocationFactory.createInvocation(DefaultInvocationFactory.java:60)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor$DispatcherDefaultingToRealMethod.interceptAbstract(MockMethodInterceptor.java:161)
    at com.att.idp.featuretoggle.core.ActivationStrategy$MockitoMock$4gFdat1K.isApplicable(Unknown Source)
    at com.att.idp.featuretoggle.web.jaxrs.FeatureToggleFilterTest.testfilterFeatureEnabled(FeatureToggleFilterTest.java:54)
```

Line 54 is indicated in the comment.

Looking at the original source of `Method.getParameterTypes()`, this could happen if `parameterTypes` is null, but I think that's unlikely. I'd have to assume that the Method instance in question is mocked in some way.

The `isApplicable` method of `ActivationStrategy` takes a parameter of type `Feature`.

**Update**:

Using the hint of the regression provided by @LMC, I added the fork properties to Surefire, and that resolved the problem. Making it not mock a Method object would be much too messy at this point.

Comment: Is maven build same version as Eclipse's one? Same jvm?

Comment: The external mvn is v3.8.2. The one used by Eclipse is 3.8.4. However, note that when I say it works in Eclipse, I'm simply doing "Run As..." "Junit Test", not running a mvn build within Eclipse.

Comment: A regression in mockito? https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2026

Comment: Please show the full pom file ... also the full output of the failing test... which surefire plugin version do you use? Which JDK ?